# Why is this eta expansion necessary?

Tags: haskell

Can someone help me understand this/point me to some reading materials? The following works fine:

```
type F a b = Functor f => f a -> f b
fComp :: F b c -> F a b -> F a c
fComp f f' = f . f'
```

But if I write `fComp = (.)` instead, the type checker complains:

```
Couldn't match type ‘b0 -> f c’
              with ‘forall (f1 :: * -> *). Functor f1 => f1 b -> f1 c’
```

(This specific example isn't particularly useful; I'm just trying to shrink an example that came up while studying lenses.)

Answer (score 12):

`fComp` has a higher-rank type and type inference for higher-rank types is very limited. It might be a little easier to understand (but much longer!) if we expand the type synonym:

```
fComp :: forall f a b c. Functor f => 
                (forall f1. Functor f1 => f1 b -> f1 c) ->
                (forall f2. Functor f2 => f2 a -> f2 b) ->
                (f a -> f c)
```

The higher-rank types of `f` and `f'` are specified explicitly in this type signature. This lets the type inference start already knowing the types of `f` and `f'` and so being able to unify them with the type of `.`.

However, if you get rid of `f` and `f'`, the type that `.` has to take is not known. Unfortunately, the system can't infer higher-rank types like this, so you get a type error.

In essence, the compiler can't create higher-rank types to fill unknowns during type inference and has to rely on programmer annotations and we need both the name (`f` and `f'`) *and* the type signature to get those annotations.

An easier example to understand would be a higher-rank `id` function:

```
myId :: (forall a. a) -> (forall b. b)
```

The definition `myId x = id x` compiles, but `myId = id` gives the following error:

```
/home/tikhon/Documents/so/eta-expansion-needed.hs:11:8:
    Couldn't match type ‘b’ with ‘forall a. a’
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for myId :: (forall a. a) -> b
          at /home/tikhon/Documents/so/eta-expansion-needed.hs:11:1
    Expected type: (forall a. a) -> b
      Actual type: b -> b
    In the expression: id
    In an equation for ‘myId’: myId = id
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

(Keep in mind that `forall b. (forall a. a) -> b` is the same as `(forall a. a) -> (forall b. b)`.)

Comment: @ErikAllik: Uh, not quite sure. I just pick stuff up as I go along. You could take a look at the paper [Typing Haskell in Haskell](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mpj/thih/thih.pdf) and it might also be covered in *Types and Programming Languages* (TAPL) along with a ton of other material.

Answer (score 6):

Let me rewrite the example using a System-F-like notation, wherein we pass types as well. Below, `\\` stands for type-abstraction (big lambda), as well as dictionary abstraction. Also, `@` stands for type/dictionary application.

Before doing that, recall the type of `(.)`:

```
(.) :: forall a b c . (b -> a) -> (c -> b) -> (c -> a)
```

Here's the annotated code (beware, not for the faint of heart):

```
fComp :: F b c -> F a b -> F a c
fComp (f :: forall f1. Functor f1 => f1 b -> f1 c)
      (f':: forall f2. Functor f2 => f2 a -> f2 b) 
   = \\ ff :: (* -> *) ->
     \\ ffD :: Functor ff ->
     ((.) @ (ff c) @ (ff b) @ (ff a))   -- instantiated composition
     (f  @ ff @ ffD)                    -- first argument of (.)
     (f' @ ff @ ffD)                    -- second argument of (.)
```

(Above I pretended `a`,`b`,`c` are type constants to avoid further type-level lambdas.)

The important parts:

- `f` and `f'` are being used at specific types. That is they are being applied to type-level arguments before being fed to `(.)`.
- `(.)` is being applied at the type level to types (`ff c`, etc) which are not the polytypes of `f` and `f'`

As you can see, the original code is far from being trivial. Type inference is able to add the needed type-level lambdas and applications. After those are added, we can not simply eta contract `fComp` anymore.

In the pointfree variant, type inference would need to do more than in the pointful case. While the first argument of `fComp` is of type `F a b`, the first argument of `(.)` must be of the form `x -> y`, which does not unify for `F a b = forall g . ...`. 
Indeed, there's no way to successfully solve the typing attempt below:

```
fComp :: F b c -> F a b -> F a c
fComp 
   = \\ ff :: (* -> *) ->
     \\ ffD :: Functor ff ->
     ((.) @ ???a @ ???b @ ???c)
```

Above there's no `???a`,... that can lead to the wanted type.

The only possibility would be to instantiate the `forall`-quantified variables hidden in the `F x y` types, but to do that we need a *point*. The compiler might eta-expand that code for you so that points appear and so can be instantiated, theoretically speaking, but in practice will not.

(Also, eta expansion is not always valid in Haskell: e.g. `seq (undefined::()->()) 3` loops while `seq (\x->(undefined::()->()) x) 3` returns `3`).

Comment: @ErikAllik Pierce's Types and programming languages is a nice one. On a more practical side, you can also get the general ideas by learning to program in a dependently-typed language like Agda or Coq. Also, you can just use Haskell and ask GHC to dump the Core intermediate representation of your program, where you can see all the type level stuff that GHC added during inference. Practice of course will not tell you everything a theory book can, but can greatly help in building some intuition (at least that was the case for me).